# How do I enable 'Show Whitespaces' in Intellij 15 Community Edition?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-15

There's no Settings → Editor → General → Appearance → Show whitespaces for me

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/wAGq3UR6EFdq

Comment: ctrl-shift-a (or cmd-shift-a) and type whitespace...

Comment: What do you see? I don't have IDEA Community 15 installed, but I see it in IDEA Ultimate 14.1.7, and it's listed in the [JetBrains documentation for 2016.01](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/appearance-2.html).